# how to find responsible query for higher RUs using log analytics of cosmos db azure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to know responsible queries which consume higher RUs from cosmos db "Diagnostic Tools" support in cosmos db azure.

I am able to store the DataPlane logs into log analytics/blob storage from azure portal. While reviewing the logs, I see field named "requestcharge_s". To my understanding this is the RU consumed by that operation.

I want to know the exact underlying query that corresponds to this log entry. How can I get that? I do see "activityId_g" field in the log entry... But don't know if there is any way to get the exact query using that field value.

I am aware that, consumed RUs get returned as one of the HTTP header value while triggering query on cosmos db.. But, I would rather want to see it on azure portal for better in-place analysis.

I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bhupendra. Based on the properties table in the [Interpret your logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging#interpret), there is no such property which logs the exact query using RUs.

In fact,any operation on Cosmos DB will consume RUs and the diagnostic logging distinguishing the operation types by `OperationName` property.

You could get below clues in above link:

1.TimeGenerated,the date and time (UTC) when the operation occurred

2.OperationName,this value can be any of the following operations: Create, Update, Read, ReadFeed, Delete, Replace, Execute, SqlQuery, Query, JSQuery, Head, HeadFeed, or Upsert.

3.activityId_g,the unique GUID for the logged operation.

4.ResourceId,the value may point to databaseRid, collectionRid, or documentRid depending on the operation performed.

5.requestCharge_s,the number of RUs that are used by the operation.

I think you could basically locate where your client-side is sending the query. If you do want to know the specific query sql, you could add logs of printing SQL to your client-side, supplemented by operating time to locate.

Answer (score 0):

To find the top consuming Cosmos query I found [this article](https://vincentlauzon.com/2020/03/04/monitoring-query-performance-in-cosmos-db). Starting from that point I made some improvements to the query and came up with this one:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB"
| where Category == "DataPlaneRequests"
| where collectionName_s == "Global"
| project activityId_g, requestCharge_s
| join kind = inner (
       AzureDiagnostics
       | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB"
       | where Category == "QueryRuntimeStatistics"
       | project activityId_g, querytext_s
) on $left.activityId_g == $right.activityId_g
| summarize sumRU = sum(todouble(requestCharge_s)), 
    avgRU = avg(todouble(requestCharge_s)), 
    countQueries = count() by querytext_s
| project sumRU, avgRU, countQueries, querytext_s
| order by sumRU desc
| limit 20
```

The main problem to get this data *easily* is that the consumed RU/s are recorded in the `DataPlaneRequests` while the concrete query is available in `QueryRuntimeStatistics`. Gladfully both share the same activityId and can be joined to get a link between both entries.

If you run this in your Logs query your results will look something like this, which quite helps to find the problematic queries (depending on your needs you probably have to order by average or count):
[image: Query results example]